# Selenium test script is failing at this step having a lambda expression

Tags: selenium, lambda

```
Assert.That(downloadedFileContents.AsEnumerable(), Has.Some.Matches<DataRow>(item => sampleDateForNonDisaTest.Contains(item.Field<string>(columnNameLastNonDOTAlcoholTest))),
                    "LR3_JTBD-263-DT :To download a specific roster of an auditing agency");
```

Comment: Expected: some item value matching lambda expression
  But was:  < <System.Data.DataRow> >

Comment: You question is not helpful for readers and not giving correct information of the problem. Please read the guidelines carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask